# Update hyperlink via userform textbox entry

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

I have a piece of code that I thought was working. What it does is it updates the text displayed in the hyperlink box and takes that last portion of the URL as the text to display. It is then suppose to update the entire hyperlink itself. When I first tested this code it worked for a few reports. 
Then I got to some reports where it would only update the text displayed correctly. I would then try to manually update the URL and it would revert back to the original hyperlink. Has anyone else ever seen this?
What would be a good work around for this problem. The only way I could get the new hyperlink to stick was to remove the old hyperlink entirely and then insert the new hyperlink.

```
Public Sub UpdateHyperLink()

Dim rng As Range, str As String
Set rng = Range("C3:I13")


str = TextBox2.Text
str2 = Right(str, Len(str) - InStrRev(str, "/"))

Application.CutCopyMode = False

With rng.Hyperlinks(1)
    .Address = TextBox2.Text
    .TextToDisplay = str2    
End Sub
```

Comment: It seems like you have an answer. "The only way I could get the new hyperlink to stick was to remove the old hyperlink entirely and then insert the new hyperlink". Have you tried altering your code to do just that and see if it works?

Comment: @IvenBach I will try this and get back to this thread.... I was just curious if anyone could explain why Excel does this. It seems to be a problem that arrives infrequently and intermittently.....